# Condition with params rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, action

What is wrong?

I have a form with radio buttons.

Form sends checked ids[] to `create` action.

I see value of params in the console, but attributes don't update.

Always assigns 9

```
<input name="ids[]" value="1"  type="radio" class="multiradio">
<input name="ids[]" value="2"  type="radio" class="multiradio">
<input name="ids[]" value="3"  type="radio" class="multiradio"> 

p params[:ids]
@advert = Advert.new(advert_params)

if (params[:ids] == "1")
  @advert.update(category: "1")
elsif (params[:ids] == "2")
  @advert.update(category: "2")
elsif (params[:ids] == 3)
  @advert.update(category: "3")
else
  @advert.update(category: "9")
end
```

Comment: value of ids[] is equal to the selected one radiobutton

Comment: ... =>"Телефон", "description"=>"ooo", "price"=>"1000", "name"=>"
80563446798"}, "ids"=>["2"], "commit"=>"Create Advert"}
["2"]

Comment: By giving the input field a name like `ids[]` the `params[:ids]` will return an array of values. That means it can include multiple different values. In the example from your comment it returns the array: `["2"]` How to fix that? It depends on if you need to have the option to select multiple values. And if so, how you want to handle it if someone requests `"1"` and `"2"`.

Comment: Thank's! Corrected The problem is that it is an array. Correspondingly, you need to address the item index.

         ...@ids = params [: ids]
         if @ids [0] == "1"  
         ...

Answer (score 0):

I think a lot is wrong to be honest... this is not exactly the way how you create checkboxes in Rails. Have you checked the form helper? Or considered using Simple Form gem?

The way you create the form:

```
#assuming you have a related model called category
simple_form_for @advert do |f|
  = f.association :category, as: :checkboxes
```

Then in the controller you simply whitelist the param and save the model:

```
def update
  @advert.update(advert_params)
end

def advert_params
  params.require(:advert).permit(category_ids: [])
end
```

Answer (score -1):

If i understood you correctly, you have a problem of setting the category value in @advert.
according to ruby syntax you have to shift your code inside blocks, that's mean you should have written your conditions like this:

```
   if (params[:ids] == "1")
      @advert.update(category: "1")
   elsif (params[:ids] == "2")
      @advert.update(category: "2")
   elsif (params[:ids] == 3)
      @advert.update(category: "3")
   else
      @advert.update(category: "9")
   end
```

take a look [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_if_else.htm).
furthermore, i would recommend you to use switch case in that case